# What thread calls the delegate when using iPhone CoreLocation framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, core-location

If I create CLLocationManager, assign it's delegate, and finally tell it to start updating, exactly which thread is calling the delegate? Some system thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't say anything, you can safely assume that the delegate will be called from the run loop (main thread or UI thread, depending on which term you prefer).

Comment: well, that would explain the deadlock I experienced then!